# Context passing in WCF pipeline

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client

Say, I'm on a client side where the chain looks something like (simplified):

1. Proxy method call
2. Parameter inspection (`IParameterInspector`)
3. Serialization/message formatting
4. Message inspection (`IClientMessageInspector`)
5. Channel

Are there any means to pass my context through the chain?

The problem i'm trying to solve is that `IParameterInspector.AfterCall()` is not get called in case of faults and I cannot obtain correlation state object i created in `IParameterInspector.BeforeCall()`, can I? But if I could store it in some context i would retrieve it in, for example, `IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply()` and be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OperationContext` is not available within `IClientMessageInspector`. Ended up with `ThreadStatic` field in hope I won't get multi-thread issues.